# Azure Data Factory: foreach loop with batchCount and item() property

Tags: foreach, azure-data-factory

I have a Data Factory pipeline with a ForEach loop where I have two activities: one to call an HTTP endpoint to retrieve a file, one to store this file into an Azure storage account.
I have set the Batch Count to 5, to have the ability to speed up the process.

I use the "item()" property in the activities inside the for each. As far as I see, when there are parallel executions, it sounds like the item() property is not relevant because there are mixed executions at the same time and the item() property could be modified by another branch of the for each loop.
What I'm looking for is the ability to read the item() value in the first step of "for each" loop, store it into a variable that will have the "for each" current loop scope, then use the content of the variable in the latter stages of the loop.
Or maybe there is a better way to manage my use case, any ideas?

Comment: Have you investigated variables in ADF?

Comment: I already set a variable in the ForEach as the first step, and use this variable in the second step which is a Copy Data activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to perform the traversal sequentially. In ADF variables are shared by threads in the heap. Multi-threaded execution of tasks cannot be controlled manually. So we need to check the `Sequential` option.
[image]

Comment: Ok but if I use this option, my pipeline takes 2h instead of 20 minutes to execute...

Comment: Unfortunately, we can not have it both ways. : (

Comment: Maybe you can copy it to a place and do further processing.

Comment: I think the solution is to pass your item() (or the members of interest) to an execute pipeline task

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today and was going through answers here on SO.
Took me some time but I was able to fix the issue.

Assume Table_Name is the item I want to loop in foreach.

> If I use @item.Table_Name for dynamic purpose then it gets me into an issue where different instances of foreach loop shares same value, that is wrong and get all failures afterward.

> If I add a set Variable task as my first step in Foreach loop to capture the @item.Table_Name value then it works as expected. Later in other steps I was able to use the Table_Name as variable at all different places which needs a dynamic input.

[image]

As shown in snapshot, add a set variable and it works.